# ADFS 2019 login page doesn't redirect to my app

Tags: openid, adfs, adfs4.0

I can use simple URL like this:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=myid.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&redirect_uri=http://localhost

and after login to google account it redirects me correctly but I can not achieve this with ADFS 2019 https://server.mylocal.local/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon
It just print "You are signed in." on screen.
I've setup a web application in ADFS console with "http://localhost" redirect address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the endpoint "/adfs/oauth2" this is using OpenID Connect.

"idpinitiatedsignon" is a SAML 2.0 endpoint and will only show SAML RP so you won't see the Google entry.

Also, ADFS only does OpenID Connect downstream not upstream so you cannot use Google to login. Upstream ADFS only supports WS-Fed and SAML 2.0.

You could do this by federating ADFS with e.g. Auth0 and then using Auth0 to do the Google login.

Answer (score 0):

This website helps me:
[blog.scottlogic.com](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html)

the correct URL is:
/adfs/oauth2/authorize?

Comment: Is this another question?

Comment: You should rather add this to the original question or add as a comment.

Comment: This is solution to my question but @rbrayb answer is a more complete answer.